# CRUD -> Add error message

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jdbc

I would like to do a CRUD but I have a problem in my variable SortieA it is NULL ? See picture here => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFhkX.png)

It's a problem in my class Album ?

```
public class Album {
    private String codeA;
    private String titreA;  
    private Date sortieA;
    private Chanteur chanteurAlb;  

    public Album() {

    }

    public Album(String codeA, String titreA, Date sortieA, Chanteur chanteurAlb) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
        this.titreA = titreA;
        this.sortieA = sortieA;
        this.chanteurAlb = chanteurAlb;
    }

    public String getCodeA() {
        return codeA;
    }

    public void setCodeA(String codeA) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
    }

    public String getTitreA() {
        return titreA;
    }

    public void setTitreA(String titreA) {
        this.titreA = titreA;
    }

    public Date getSortieA() {
        return sortieA;
    }

    public void setSortieA(Date sortieA) {
        this.sortieA = sortieA;
    }

    public Chanteur getChanteurAlb() {
        return chanteurAlb;
    }

    public void setChanteurAlb(Chanteur chanteurAlb) {
        this.chanteurAlb = chanteurAlb;
    }
```

Here is my request

```
public boolean insertAlbum (Album alb)
    {
        boolean ok = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().actionQuery("Insert into album (CodeA, TitreA, SortieA, IdentC) values ('" + alb.getCodeA() + "','" + alb.getTitreA() +
        "'," + alb.getSortieA() + "," + alb.getChanteurAlb().getIdentC() + ")");
        return ok;
    }
```

Do you have an idea please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3DAt.png)

Comment: How can you tell if the code you've posted is sufficient for us to tell what is *causing* the problem? From my view, I don't think that you have, and a [mcve] would help immensely from our perspective. Please consider creating one and posting this with your question.

Comment: Besides the MCVE suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels note: do **not** post (links to) images of **textual** information - post the text itself (as text). Especially when the crux of that message is not in English. (Google does not yet translate text from images!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very obvious that the date you enter in the form is not set in your Album object since you get null in the sql statement. So you need to figure out where it gets lost.
Once you have solved that you need to parse your date into a correctly formatted string in the insertAlbum() method because using the raw Date in the sql string won’t work.